# Comparing time and date in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, date, time, comparison

Lets say there are two textboxes, one to enter in a date and the other to enter in time. Below is an example:

```
<p><strong>Date:</strong> <input type="text" id="datetxt"></p>

Example of how date is displayed: 25-05-1995

<p><strong>Time:</strong> <input type="text" id="timetxt"></p>

Example of how time is displayed: 14:25
```

Can someone suggest a way in javascript to compare values of the date and time from the textboxes to the current date and time so if the current date and time is past the date and time entered in the textboxes, then it should display and alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var dateParts = document.getElementById("datetxt").value.split("-");
var timeParts = document.getElementById("timetxt").value.split(":");

var valueDate = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1) ,dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

if( (new Date).getTime() > valueDate .getTime() )
{
   alert("passed");
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TJEMr/

Comment: Both answers are great. Thank you. I have gone for this one as it does it for all date and times. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You need to massage your date string into a [compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date format:

```
    //datetxt textbox value, split on dashes
var date = "25-05-1995".split("-"), 
    //timetxt textbox value
    time = "14:25",
    //put it into format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm and creates a date object from it
    dateObj = new Date(date[2] + '-' + date[1] + '-' + date[0] + 'T' + time);

//if today is greater than we have passed that DateTime
if(new Date() > dateObj) {
    alert("After entered date");
} else {
    alert("Not passed yet!");
}
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fenjq/3/)